# Show id and Count the same Foreign Key

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using `MySql`. I have a table with 2 column `id (Primary Key)` and `id_of (Foreign Key)`. Number of `id` can have the same `id_of`. I want to get all the `id` and get the count of rows having the `id_of` related to the `id`. How to make this `sql` query/queries? So far I could only get this:

`SELECT id, (SELECT COUNT(id_of) FROM test_table) AS count FROM test_table;`

`database's table:`

```
  id  |  id_of
----------------
abasb | 2131233
hdafd | 2131233
fajdf | 3546541
pogad | 3546541
afdaj | 2131233
fafda | 8661565
```

`the results I want:`

```
  id  |  count
----------------
abasb |    3
hdafd |    3
fajdf |    2
pogad |    2
afdaj |    3
fafda |    1
```

Comment: tag your dbms name

Comment: question has been updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just need a bit of correction your query

```
  SELECT id, 
 (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test_table t2 where t2.id_of=t1.id_of) AS count
  FROM test_table t1
```

Comment: here is the [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=381ef5ede7d3ed58aa87374b9b018476) @Amandeep Singh

Answer (score 0):

You may try this...

```
  ; with cte as ( select distinct id_of, count(*) as Coun from testtable )
  select t.id , c.coun from testtable as t inner join cte as c on t.id_of=c.id_of
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
select id , count(*) over (partition by id_of) id_of from Yourtable
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use ajoin on subqiery for count

```
select  a.id, t.count_of_id_of 
from test_table a 
inner join     (
  select  id_of, count(*)  count_of_id_of
  from  test_table 
  group by id_of 
) t on t.id_of= a.id_of
```